# CSS menu: dropdown items display as block

Tags: css, menu, block

Since I am discovering and struggling with CSS dropdown menus, I hope you won´t mind this simple question. I have a fully functioning CSS dropdown menu, but just after I prevented the horizontal menu from wrapping (in case the browser would be resized), I am having trouble displaying the dropdown items below each other (block). Instead they are now also displayed next to each other (inline-block).

Can anybody tell me which line I have to add? This was the code that I added that changed both my menu from wrapping (good) and my dropdown items from being displayed below each other:

```
nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
float: none;
}
```

Full CSS menu code:

```
/* Set general properties for main menu items */

nav ul {
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(200,220,154,0) 30%, #c8dc9a 90%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(200,220,154,0) 30%, #c8dc9a 90%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(200,220,154,0) 30%, #c8dc9a 90%); 
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(200,220,154,0) 30%, #c8dc9a 90%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(200,220,154,0) 30%, #c8dc9a 90%);
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-size: 16px; 
white-space: nowrap;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
}

nav ul:after {
    content: ""; 
    clear: both; 
    display: block;
}

nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
float: none;
border-bottom: 3px solid #244612;
padding:0 0 0 7px;
}

/* Set hover properties for main menu items */

nav ul li:hover {
    background: #e29a0e;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(226,154,14,0) 0%, #e29a0e 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(226,154,14,0) 0%, #e29a0e 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(226,154,14,0) 0%, #e29a0e 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(226,154,14,0) 0%, #e29a0e 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(226,154,14,0) 0%, #e29a0e 100%);
}

    nav ul li:hover a {
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    nav ul li:hover ul li a{    
        color: #757575;
    }

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 13px;
    color: #757575; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Set properties for hiding/unhiding dropdown items */ 

nav ul ul {
display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

/* Set general properties for dropdown menu items */

nav ul ul {
background: #F7F7F7; 
border-radius: 0px; 
padding: 0;
position: absolute; 
top: 100%;
margin-left: -7px;
font-size: 14px;
white-space: normal;
float: left;
}

/* Set hover properties for dropdown menu items */  

nav ul ul li {
    border-top: 1px solid #C9CCCF;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #C9CCCF;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}

    nav ul ul li a {
        padding: 10px 25px;
    }   

        nav ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
            background: #e29a0e;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that I understood your question correctly!
Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b68PB/).

All you need to add is

`nav ul li ul li{
    display:block;
}`

And that should be it!

Comment: The required selector is already in the CSS, no need for this new one - just add your `display: block` rule to  `nav ul ul li`.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you both so much! That indeed solved my problem :)